# git configuration to prompt for username on push

Tags: git

I have several git repositories on my computer. Some of them ask for my username every time I push, but others do not.

Why is this? Is there a global git configuration or setting I need to change?

Running linux mint if it matters.

Comment: Probably some of the repos are using `https://` remote, while others are using `git@github.com` remote. There could be other reasons too, but check and compare the output of `git remote -v`.

Comment: This manual page describes how to provide credentials to avoid repeated authentication: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html You can read up on the credential helpers that store passwords for future use https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be sure about your git local repository status, inside your git local repository folder type command

```
git config --list
```

to see affected configuration.

*We have 2 type of Git configuration:*

**Global** (If you use 2 or more than git servers, I don't recommend this way)

```
git config --global user.name "Mr. Joe"
git config --global user.email "joe@example.com"
```

**Repository level** (If you use many git servers, It's recommended), at repo R1:

```
git config user.name "Mr. Rilcon"
git config user.email "rilcon@example.com"
```

at repo R2:

```
git config user.name "Mr. Happy"
git config user.email "saturday@example.com"
```

Then you will avoid problems, Git won't ask you username or password many times.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like some of your repositories are pulling the credentials from the credential store. If you check the example below from the git documentation you can see how to store it for each repo. [example below from git-credential-store documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>

[several days later]
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
[your credentials are used automatically]
```